# How to prove that a metric space is compact if it is complete and totally bounded?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

How to prove that  a metric space is compact if  it is complete and totally bounded?

Wiki wrote  that it is a generalisation of Heine–Borel theorem  but I can't prove it.

Comment: Look up Munkres's Topology or other standard text.

Comment: See for example here (http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/254a-notes-8-a-quick-review-of-point-set-topology/), Theorem 1

Comment: Did you try Google? For example searching for [metric compact complete "totally bounded"](http://www.google.com/search?q=metric+compact+complete+%22totally+bounded%22) or [metric compact complete "totally bounded" site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=metric+compact+complete+%22totally+bounded%22+site:math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Some posts on MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774111/a-metric-space-is-compact-iff-it-is-complete-and-totally-bounded, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733167/a-metric-space-is-compact-if-and-only-if-its-complete-and-totally-bounded, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109550/totally-bounded-complete-implies-compact (you could probably find more)

Comment: Also searching for the same phrase in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?q=metric+compact+complete+%%totally+bounded%22) returns lots of hits.